# How can I glue/identify inclusions in two structures in MMT?

Tags: dependent-type, theorem-proving, formal-methods, mmt

I'd like to formalize formal languages and their semantics in [MMT](https://uniformal.github.io/) and define a general notion of *semantics equivalence* of two semantics wrt. *one* syntax. Precisely, encoding the latter turns out to be an identification/glueing that I have no idea on how to do in MMT. Let me elaborate on my concrete formalization setup next.

Below is a simplified formalization showing my approach. Based on a theory `Meta` aggregating both the logical framework LF and some logic, I start in `Syntax` defining a general notion of expressions and typings. Then, in `Semantics` I define on top a semantics, here for simplicity, only a deductive semantics, i.e. a derivability relation.

```
theory Meta : http://cds.omdoc.org/urtheories?LF=  
  // some logic giving us a type `prop` of propositions,
  // a notion of derivability ⊦, biimplication ⇔ etc. ❙
  include ?Logic ❙
❙

theory Syntax : ?Meta =
  // type for expressions ❙
  expr: type ❙

  // a typing relation
  typing_rel: expr ⟶ expr ⟶ prop ❙

  // ... ❙
❚

theory Semantics : ?Meta=
  include ?Syntax ❙

  // a deductive semantics: "derivable e" says e is a theorem ❙
  derivable: expr ⟶ prop ❙
❚
```

Given this, I want to define the equivalence of *two* such semantics wrt. to *one* syntax. Encoding the first part is easy, see below; but I am having trouble encoding the latter requirement.

```
theory SemanticsEquivalence : ?Meta =
  structure syn : ?Syntax ❚

  // how can I force sem1|?Syntax = sem2|?Syntax = syn ❙
  structure sem1 : ?Semantics = ❚
  structure sem2 : ?Semantics = ❚

  is_equivalent: {e: syn/expr} ⊦ (sem1/derivable e) ⇔ (sem2/derivable e) ❙
❚
```

**How do I glue/identify the inclusions of `Syntax` in both `sem1` and `sem2`?**

Comment: meta remark: [MMT](https://uniformal.github.io/)  is a formal system developed in the [kwarc research group](https://kwarc.info/). We are investigating whether we can use StackOverflow for questions on that, hence the mmt tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Use defined inclusions within the structures:

```
theory SemanticsEquivalence : ?Meta =
  structure syn : ?Syntax = ❚
    
  structure sem1 : ?Semantics =
    include ?Syntax ❘ = ?SemanticsEquivalence?syn ❙
  ❚
  structure sem2 : ?Semantics =
    include ?Syntax ❘ = ?SemanticsEquivalence?syn ❙
  ❚

  is_equivalent: {e: syn/expr} ⊦ (sem1/derivable e) ⇔ (sem2/derivable e) ❙
❚
```

### Explanation

The theory of why this works is much deeper than the code above might suggest. It requires understanding  the three aspects elaborated on below. I aggregated this information from the [official MMT docs on implicit morphisms, structures, and includes](https://uniformal.github.io//doc/language/implicit.html) and from personal communication with [@Dennis Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12645949/dennis-m%c3%bcller).

1. **Structures induce theory morphisms**

   For example, `structure syn : ?Syntax = ❚` within the theory `SemanticsEquivalence` has two effects: first, it copies every declaration `Syntax?d` to a declaration `SemanticsEquivalence?syn/d` where `syn/d` is just a "complex" name for the copy. Second, the structure also induces a theory morphism `Syntax -> SemanticsEquivalence` that maps every declaration `Syntax?d` to the copy `SemanticsEquivalence?syn/d`.

   This behavior of structures might look a bit simplistic here, but that's only because the structure `syn` has an empty body. If you had instead

   ```
   theory SemanticsEquivalence : ?Meta =
     otherExpr: type ❙
     structure syn : ?Syntax =
       expr = otherExpr ❙
     ❚
   ❚
   ```

   then the induced theory morphism would contain the mappings `Syntax?expr := SemanticsEquivalence?otherExpr`, `Syntax?typing_rel := SemanticsEquivalence?syn/typing_rel`, i.e. only `Syntax?typing_rel` got copied.
2. **Inclusions induce theory morphisms, too**

   For example, with `theory Semantics = include ?Syntax ❙ ... ❚` the inclusion of `Syntax` within `Semantics` has similar effects as structures with empty body: every declaration `Syntax?d` is accessible within `Semantics` under the same URI (thus in some sense a copy), and there is an induced morphism — an implicit one even — `Syntax -> Semantics` that maps every declaration identity-like: `Syntax?d := Syntax?d`.
3. **Inclusions, as declarations, may also have a definition**

   Let us consider this by means of an example. Consider we had a morphism `m: Syntax -> Semantics'` where `theory Semantics' = include ?Syntax ❘ = m ❙ ... ❚`. Now, the inclusion of `Syntax` *no longer* induces the trivial identity-like morphism, but instead takes `m`. For instance, if the `...` part mentions a declaration `Syntax?d`, actually `m(Syntax?d)` is taken.

   Let us mix this insight with the previous ones. Consider the following code:

   ```
   theory SemanticsEquivalence : ?Meta =
     structure syn : ?Syntax = ❚

     structure sem1 : ?Semantics =
       include ?Syntax ❘ = ?SemanticsEquivalence?syn
     ❚

     // other structure... ❙
   ❚
   ```

   By the first insight, `syn` induces a morphism `Syntax -> SemanticsEquivalence`, which is accessible via `?SemanticsEquivalence?syn`. Moreover, by the first and second insights, we know that the inclusion of `Syntax` within the structure is a special kind of morphism, namely `Syntax -> SemanticsEquivalence` — note the codomain! Finally, by the third insight, we can define that inclusion with a fitting morphism, namely with `?SemanticsEquivalence?syn`. And this achieves precisely the gluing we wanted.