# View between theories both including a common theory in MMT

Tags: syntax, mmt

I have two theories B and C both including a common theory A. My goal is to specify a view `BC: B → C` in a convenient way *without* providing mappings for all constants in A.

```
fixmeta ur:?LF ❚

theory A =
    a : type ❙
❚

theory B =
    include ?A ❙
    b : type ❙
❚

theory C =
    include ?A ❙
    c : type ❙
❚

view BC : ?B → ?C =
    // do I need to map all constants of A here? ❙
    b = c ❙
❚
```

Currently, BC is not total, e.g. the constant `a` from `A` has no mapping.

I would like to not have to care about A when defining BC and just map every constant in the A from B to the identical constant in A from C.

Is this possible? Is there some sort of identity-view from A to A that can just be included into BC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution.**

```
view BC : ?B → ?C =
    include ?A ❙
    b = c ❙
❚
```

**Explanation.** The syntax `include ?A ❙` in your theories B and C, besides other things, also acts as a normal declaration in the same way as constant declarations are declarations. For views to be valid, all undefined declarations of the domain theory need to be mapped to something. In particular, include declarations need to be mapped to morphisms, which describe the morphism action to be inherited and applied on for the included part of the domain.

Hence, you can achieve mapping all declarations in A to themselves by mapping `include ?A` to the identity morphism on A, which exactly represents the desired mapping. In MMT surface syntax, this can be achieved via `include ?A ❘ = IDENTITY ?A`, or equivalently, by the synactic sugar `include ?A`.

In general, if you got a view `v: B → C` and B includes A, then v must map `include ?A` to a morphism `A → C`. Above, we mapped it to a morphism `A → A` (namely, the identity), which is also a morphism of the form `A → C` since A is included in C.

See the second reference below on gluing inclusions in structures for an example where the assigned morphism is *not* the identity.

**Further references.**

- [Official documentation on includes and implicit morphisms](https://uniformal.github.io//doc/language/implicit.html)
- [How to glue/identify inclusions in two structures in MMT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63115393/603003)